# How to use nvd3 examples on local machine

Tags: nvd3.js

I wanted to use nvd3 examples that are live on their website: http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav

What should I do? The example link has multiple tabs, should I copy paste and save all those codes in one folder and open it an index.html ?

Answer (score 5):

I would download their source and use the examples in their examples folder, as it's tidily set up for you to manipulate.

Source: https://github.com/novus/nvd3 (either clone or download as a .zip)

PS I would use Firefox to open them as Chrome can be really testy about using files locally and not from a webserver.

Comment: and don't use the default index.html...use site.html